# Saving NSMutableArray to the iPhone Documents Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, data-storage, writetofile

I am trying to create a mutable array with objects of a custom class called Dog and save it to a file in the iPhone documents directory to be later read out of the file and back into my application.  I am trying to use NSArray's writeToFile:atomically: method to accomplish this, but when I test the results of this method, it always returns a value of NO, and the file is not created, and the array is not stored.  I have a few questions about this.  What file format should I save my array to?  What does it mean to atomically write an array to a file? How do I read out the contents of the file once the array is stored there And most importantly, why is my array not being stored into a file at the specified path?  Thank you in advance and here is the code that I am using within my app's viewDidLoad method:

```
NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                          (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0];
dogFilePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayDogsFile.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@",dogFilePath);

Dog *dog1 = [[Dog alloc] init];
dog1.name = @"Dog1";
Dog *dog2 = [[Dog alloc] init];
dog2.name = @"Dog2";
Dog *dog3 = [[Dog alloc] init];
dog3.name = @"Dog3";

NSMutableArray *arrayDogs = [NSMutableArray array];
[arrayDogs addObject: dog1];
[arrayDogs addObject: dog2];
[arrayDogs addObject: dog3];

//Sorts the array in alphabetical order according to name – compareDogNames: is defined in the Dog class
arrayDogs = (NSMutableArray *)[arrayDogs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareDogNames:)];


if ([arrayDogs writeToFile:dogFilePath atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"Data writing successful");
else
    NSLog(@"Data writing unsuccessful");
```

Comment: Look into archiving / unarchiving - Your dog class will have to adopt the NSCoding protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not save your array of objects because objects are not NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary.You could rather use [NSKeyArchiver and NSKeyUnArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000949-BABGBHCA.)
**For example:**
`#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"`

```
@interface Dog : NSObject {**NSCoding**}//your class must conform to NSCoding Protocol  
@property (retain) NSString *Name;  
@end
```

The implementation needs some additional code. We need to implement the NSCoding protocol, which means 
**two additional methods. (initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:)**
`#import "Dog.h"`

```
@implementation Dog 
@synthesize Name;  
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder{    
    if ((self = [super init])) {  
        Name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Name"];  
}  
    return self;  
}



-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder{  
    [encoder encodeObject:Name forKey:@"Name"];  
}
```

Once we implement the protocol, saving will look like this:
    // Save method
// We initialise our object and set the values

```
Dog *dog1 = [[Dog alloc] init];  
dog1.Name= @"Dog1";  
Dog *dog2 = [[Dog alloc] init];  
dog2.Name= @"Dog2";  
Dog *dog3 = [[Dog alloc] init];  
dog3.Name= @"Dog3";    
NSMutableArray *arrayDogs = [NSMutableArray array];  
[arrayDogs addObject: dog1];  
[arrayDogs addObject: dog2];  
[arrayDogs addObject: dog3];
```

//Sorts the array in alphabetical order according to name – compareDogNames: is defined in the Dog class

```
arrayDogs = (NSMutableArray *)[arrayDogs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareDogNames:)];
```

// Store the array

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:arrayDogs toFile:dogFilePath];
```

//load the array*

```
NSMutableArray* retreivedADogObjs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dogFilePath]; 
@end
```

Hope it will help you
Happy to help.*

Answer (score 1):

Look at `NSKeyedArchiver` & `NSKeyedUnarchiver` Specifically you want `+ archiveRootObject:toFile:` to save the file and `+ unarchiveObjectWithFile:` to extract it again.

You will need to implement the NSCoding protocol in your `Dog` class as well to make this work. You just need to use something like `- encodeObject: forKey:` and `– decodeObjectForKey:` for each of your properties. The docs for NSCoder will show you which method to use for which kinds of property types (for example with `BOOL`s you use `- encodeBool: forKey:`).

Answer (score 0):

**Industrial answer:**
There's a whole subject for this in the SDK called "[Archiving and Serialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000949-BABGBHCA)".

**If you don't have time to learn, but your dog does:**
Teach your Dog two new tricks:  1. How to render myself as a dictionary of strings and ints and so on.  2. How to init myself from that same kind of dictionary.  This is basically a ghetto version of the industrial answer.

```
// Dog.m
- (NSDictionary *)asDictionary {

    NSMutableDictionary *answer = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [answer setValue:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [answer setValue:self.numberOfBones forKey:@"numberOfBones"];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:answer];
}

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
        self.numberOfBones = [dictionary valueForKey:@"numberOfBones"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When writing:

```
[arrayDogs addObject: [dog1 asDictionary]];
```